# Synchronous data transfer from SQL Server to Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have a requirement like:

> The table is present both in a SQL Server Database and an Oracle database with appropriate data types. Whenever a record is inserted into or updated in SQL server database table, then the same operation us to be performed on the Oracle database table.

**Example:** Table_SQL in SQL Server DB and Table_Oracle in Oracle DB. A record with id=1 is inserted into Table_SQL, now the same record will also be inserted into Table_Oracle automatically without running an external package or anything.

Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: Found an old thread here.In Summary: create Linked Server in MS SQL that points to Oracle via OLE/DB. You have to install Oracle Client there on the MS SQL host.
.then do  insert into target_table select * from oracle_linked_server.schema.table...Thread:https://community.oracle.com/thread/2393539?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 2):

One option with SQL Server is [Heterogeneous Database Replication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151149%28v=sql.120%29.aspx). This works with SQL Server as a source and destination being either of:

> The following non-SQL Server databases are supported as Subscribers to snapshot and transactional publications:
>
> - Oracle for all platforms that Oracle supports.
> - IBM DB2 for AS400, MVS, Unix, Linux, and Windows.

[Snapshot Replication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151832%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) is best if:

> Using snapshot replication by itself is most appropriate when one or more of the following is true:
>
> - Data changes infrequently.
> - It is acceptable to have copies of data that are out of date with respect to the Publisher for a period of time.
> - Replicating small volumes of data.
> - A large volume of changes occurs over a short period of time.

Therefore it seems that [Transactional Replication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151176%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) is your best option:

> Transactional replication is typically used in server-to-server environments and is appropriate in each of the following cases:
>
> - You want incremental changes to be propagated to Subscribers as they occur.
> - The application requires low latency between the time changes are made at the Publisher and the changes arrive at the Subscriber.
> - The application requires access to intermediate data states. For example, if a row changes five times, transactional replication allows an application to respond to each change (such as firing a trigger), not simply the net data change to the row.
> - The Publisher has a very high volume of insert, update, and delete activity.
> - The Publisher or Subscriber is a non-SQL Server database, such as Oracle.

---

You could also look down the Linked Server road and update it with a trigger. I think it could be a lot easier to setup if you have only a single table to sync.

However I will only insert some links as I have never tried it and can't try it right now:

- Microsoft [How to set up and troubleshoot a linked server to an Oracle database in SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/280106)
- MSDN [Creating a Linked Server for Oracle in 64bit SQL Server](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2013/10/02/creating-a-linked-server-for-oracle-in-64bit-sql-server.aspx)
- MSDN [How to get up and running with Oracle and Linked Servers](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2015/07/31/how-to-get-up-and-running-with-oracle-and-linked-servers/)
- Technet [Oracle Provider for OLE DB](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190618%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Be careful with the 32/64-bit providers and choose the right one.

Comment: Is it possible to replicate the transnational data automatically to Table_oracle whenever a record is inserted into Table_SQL table?

Comment: yes using transactional replication or linkedserver+trigger

Comment: Could you please guide me on this how exactly my approach should be? .. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For linked server you can follow the link at and tutorial at the end. You then only have to add a trigger which will do an insert of the inserted row into the linked table. For replication, you have to study and understand how it works. This is a complex subject. You can first start here: [Lesson 1: Publishing Data Using Transactional Replication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337453.aspx)